# A very basic combinatorial question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorial-proofs

Today when I was reading my algebra book I encountered this following problems,
given the set $$A = \{1, 2, \dots, n-1, n \}$$

I realized that if I just list all the possible $(i,j)$ such that $i,j \in A$ and $i < j$, then this gives you exactly all the possible ways of pick $2$ elements from $A$ without repetition.

This is intuitively correct, but is there a way to proves this? I have zero experience with combinatorial math, but here is my attempt:

Given $(i,j)$ such that $i,j \in A$ and $i < j$, this is clearly a way of pick $2$ elements from $A$. On the other hand, if I choose $i$ and $j$ from $A$, by possible rearrangement, we can assume that $i < j$, then this gives you an element $(i,j)$ such that $i,j \in A$ and $i < j$. This gives you a bijective correspondence between all $(i,j)$ where $i,j \in A$ and $i < j$, and all possible way of pick $2$ elements from $A$.

is this proof correct?

Further, can I generalize this to the following statement,
the list of all $(i,j,k)$ where $i,j,k \in A$ and $i<j<k$ would gives you all possible ways of pick $3$ elements from $A$?

Comment: What is the actual question you are trying to answer? Are you just trying to count all possible two element subsets?

Comment: There is an obvious bijection between $\{(i,j)~:~i<j,~i,j\in A\}$ and $\{\{i,j\}~:~i,j\in A,~i\neq j\}$... mapping $(i,j)$ to $\{i,j\}$.  That there is such a bijection proves that the sets are indeed of the same cardinality by definition.